# Change of entropy in irreversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

When calculating entropy change for a irreversible process,do I assume a reversible path and then integrated it?

Comment: That will give you a _lower bound_, but not the actual entropy change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have determined the final state of the system for the irreversible process (say using the 1st law of thermodynamics), you *devise* an *alternate* reversible process path between the same initial and final end states and integrate along that path.  For further details on how to do this, see the following link:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Comment: Thanks!The example#2 in the reference is so much helpful!

Comment: So why don't you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If the endpoints of the irreversible path are equilibrium points *and* they can also be connected with a reversible path then the answer is yes, because the entropy is a state function. Complications ensue if there is no reversible path connecting the endpoints of the irreversible path or the irreversible process does not start/end in thermodynamic equilibrium. An example for the latter is ferromagnetic hysteresis or plastic deformation, see Bridgman: "The Thermodynamics of Plastic Deformation and Generalized Entropy", REV. MOD. PHYS. VOL. 22. NUMBER 1 JANUARY, 1950. and Tolman & Fine: "On the Irreversible Production of Entropy" REV. MOD. PHYS. VOL. 20, NUMBER 1 JANUARY, 1948